# AngularJS -- Resources and using them before the fulfilled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a big issue with Resources.

I created a mod to hold the resource, I have to use the same data in many different locations almost at the same time.  one bigest is  to populate a select list.

I can populate the select list with no problems, but the default selection is always blank.

I tried to use

```
 $scope.ServersList = Resource.List();
 $scope.Server = $scope.ServersList[1];
```

I tried to add a watch and it never went off when the promise was fulfilled;

This will populate the list but will not set the default. Im looking for solutions to the problem of the promise not being fulfilled tell after Server is set.

Comment: Server list return a list of Name,value pairs to populate an select list on the page.  I wanted to set the default pair for the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
Resource.List().then(function(server){
  $scope.ServersList = server;
  $scope.Server = server[1]
});
```

regards

Comment: I ended up using this to solve this issue: `    ServerList.then(function(server){
        $scope.serverlist = server;
        $scope.ServerName =  $scope.serverlist["data"][0]; } `

Answer (score 0):

It hard to say whats going on with the information provided, but if this is happening inside a async call then make sure you are using apply.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.ServersList = Resource.List();
  $scope.Server = $scope.ServersList[1];
});
```